# Parenting in the USA

Tags: usa, legal, culture, cultural-awareness

My company wants me to temporally do some project in the USA (6months). I want to take my family with me. We raise our children quite independent.

For example:
The oldest (7) is allowed to many things on her own (like meeting friends outdoor), she can even go tome some places without asking (playground in the neighbourhood). 
The younger (5) is allowed to this stuff with supervision of his older sister and some things on his own (like buying milk from the neighbourhood store). 
The youngest (2) will be trusted to stuff together with the oldest (like they shop in one store and I shop in the one next to it). They are also allowed to wear what they want (and if they not want to wear any clothes they are allowed).

Now my wife read this (from the foreign ministry of Germany)

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/00-SiHi/UsaVereinigteStaatenSicherheit.html

Which essentially says that all this is intolerable in the US and one would even face legal consequences (for some of things mentioned above). Of course our children will probably be not allowed to do that much in the first time. (Note that there will be hardly any language barrier, as my wife is Australian and speaks to the children in English)

But is it true that this rules are enforced (children are not allowed to be on their own before 8/12) and we could face legal consequences in the USA if we parent our children their in similar style? Also will their be any problems if we allow our children to be without clothes in public?

If this is true I might have to refuse doing this project.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about parenting not travel

Comment: http://www.freerangekids.com is a good resource for this kind of question.

Comment: @pnuts or parenting.se

Comment: There have been some well publicized incidents of parents facing charges for allowing their children to walk unaccompanied to the park (for example), but there is also some backlash against this from people who think more like you about how to raise their children.  Anyway, it's just six months, and spending that time in another culture will more likely enrich them than stifle them, even if they are less free in certain respects during those six months.

Comment: It really depends on where in the US you'll be. A child unaccompanied outdoors in inner city Baltimore is a much different scenario than one in small town Colorado.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is largely independent of the length of the stay, so this information should be removed and then it could be on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Parenting.SE

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, actually, if you look at the statistics, it depends far more on *who* you are.  If you're a white, middle- or upper-class married parent from a "respectable" country like Germany, you're far less likely to have problems than if you're a poor black single mother from someplace like Brazil.